# product impressions in google analytics come as events but are not shown in funnel report

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

i have an enhanced ecommerce set up on my site via GTM, and everything works fine except impressions.
i see them as evens in the Events session:

[image]

but not in the Shopping Behavior funnel:

[image]

i already checked the 8192 dataLayer bytes payload limit, and it is ok at least in some cases.

i have tried to set up a Product Impression tag both as a PageView and as Event, and this did not help.
do you have any clue what else could I check?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the event arrives does not mean that it contains EE information, anyway that column does not represent the 'product impressions' but the 'product detail impressions', so you are not sending to Google Analytics the 'detail' information: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#details

Comment: You're welcome, mark answer as solved and useful, pls